# Insertion in Binary Tree(Level Order)

Tags: java, data-structures

refer to 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/binary-search-tree-insertion/problem

The problem is I have passed all test cases except test case #5

My code is:

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}


static Node Insert(Node root,int value) {
// Level order traversal
    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    Node newnode = new Node();
    newnode.data=value;
    if(root!=null) 
        q.offer(root);

    while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node tmp = q.poll();
        if(tmp.data >= value) {
            if(tmp.left!=null) 
                q.offer(tmp.left);
            else {
                tmp.left = newnode;
                break;
            }
        } else {
        if(tmp.right!=null) 
            q.offer(tmp.right);
        else { tmp.right = newnode; break;}
        }
    }
       return root;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

One error I can see is in this part of the code -

```
    if(tmp.data >= value) {
        if(tmp.left != null) 
            q.offer(tmp.left);
        else {
            tmp.left = newnode;
            break;
        }
    }
```

See, here even if the value to be entered is equal to the root, you're still inserting it in the Left Subtree.

Don't you think that is a mistake ?

This is what I could find.

Hope this helps !